# How do I get an onclick event of SVG embedded in HTML to display in the HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

First of all I am a javascript and svg noob and can’t seem to find an answer on the net to my specific issues and starting to have nightmares... Perhaps I'm just not phrasing the search query correctly... Anyway... Ok, so I’ve designed a floorplan displaying rooms using svg and embedded the svg into my html doc using the "object" tag. On the right side of my webpage I have a dropdown list of the rooms. On click I want the room info to display as well as the room to be highlighted on the floorplan. This I’ve accomplished with a javascript function. Yayness. Now for the problems:

First problem – When a user clicks a different room option, the previous selected room’s image is still highlighted. How do I get it to default back to previous state when the option changes?

Second problem – I also want the user to be able to click on the room on the floorplan itself and have the same info displayed on the right hand side of the page. I essentially want to use the same function for two different elements. I’ve tried copying the script into the svg code, but nothing. Is it because the svg is an embedded object in the html?

Any suggestions would be appreciated, including whether I’m going about this whole thing the right way…

```
<html>
<object id="cres2svg" data="crescent2map.svg" type="image/svg+xml" style="float: left;"></object>

<select name="boardroomList" style="font-size: 12px;">
<option onclick="teamworkDetail()">Teamwork</option>
<option onclick="visionDetail()">Vision</option>
</select>

<h3 id="headerDetails" style="margin-left: 680px; text-align: left; color: rgb(0, 0, 153); font-    family: arial; font-size: 14px;">Header
details go here</h3>
<p id="paraDetails" style="margin-left: 680px; text-align: left; color: rgb(0, 0, 153); font-family: arial; font-size: 12px;">Paragraph details to go here</p>
</html>

<script>
function visionDetail()
{
var cres2 = document.getElementById("cres2svg");
var svgDoc = cres2.contentDocument;
var visionRoom = svgDoc.getElementById("visionRoom");
visionRoom.getAttributeNode("style").value="fill:green;stroke:red;opacity:1";
document.getElementById("headerDetails").innerHTML= "Vision Room";
document.getElementById("paraDetails").innerHTML="The Vision Room is located..."}


function teamworkDetail()
{
var cres2 = document.getElementById("cres2svg");
var svgDoc = cres2.contentDocument;
var teamworkRoom = svgDoc.getElementById("teamworkRoom");
teamworkRoom.getAttributeNode("style").value="fill:green;stroke:red;opacity:1";
document.getElementById("headerDetails").innerHTML= "Teamwork Room";
document.getElementById("paraDetails").innerHTML="The Teamwork Room is located...";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't the most elegant way to approach the issue because you're having to repeat the same code for each room.  A preferred method would be to create a function that accepts the name of the room and then does the same thing as your two separate functions:

```
function showRoomDetail(roomId)
{
  var cres2 = document.getElementById("cres2svg");
  var svgDoc = cres2.contentDocument;
  var roomRef = svgDoc.getElementById(roomId);
      //....etc  Although you'd also have to maybehold the details of each room in an array of objects
}
```

Should you not wish to go with the concept above and instead keep it the way you have it.  The issue that you are having is that you need to manually reset the style of the other rooms for a call to a specific room:

```
function visionDetail()
{
  var cres2 = document.getElementById("cres2svg");
  var svgDoc = cres2.contentDocument;
  var visionRoom = svgDoc.getElementById("visionRoom");
  visionRoom.getAttributeNode("style").value="fill:green;stroke:red;opacity:1";
  svgDoc.getElementById("teamworkRoom").getAttributeNode("style").value="";  // sets the style to empty
  svgDoc.getElementById("anotherRoomId").getAttributeNode("style").value="";  // sets the style to empty
  document.getElementById("headerDetails").innerHTML= "Vision Room";
  document.getElementById("paraDetails").innerHTML="The Vision Room is located..."
}
```

Comment: Answered my first problem. Thanks :) I'm yet to resolve the second one... :(